# How to find the index of a value within an Array, when the Array's values are separated by lines?

Tags: javascript

Good evening, I am having a lot of trouble with an array that has values separated by multiple lines.

The array is getting its information from a tab-delimited text file, and the purpose of this is for me to scan through the Array with a for-loop to search for specific values within the Array.  When I scan for the specific values, my program will return the value, and the rest of the line it is in... as well as all other lines the value is in.

The next step is to scan for other values in said lines.... but I can't seem to get the Index of a value, if the value in several lines down.

Is there any way to search through *all* of the lines in an Array for a specific value?

EDIT -  Here is the code I have so far:

```
this.importDataObject("MED & DIAGNOSIS & ICD-10.txt", 
"C:/Users/dell/Documents/MED & DIAGNOSIS & ICD-10.txt");
var oFile = this.getDataObjectContents("MED & DIAGNOSIS & ICD-10.txt");
var cFile = util.stringFromStream(oFile, "utf-8");
var fileArray = cFile.split('\n');
var Medical1 = "xanax";

if(Medical1.valueAsString != ""){
for (i = 0; i < fileArray.length; i++) { 
    Index = fileArray[i].indexOf(Medical1.value);
    if(Index > -1) Cartographer = fileArray[i].split('\t');
    if(Index > -1) MedAnalysis = Cartographer[0];
    if(Index > -1) BrandAnalysis = Cartographer[1];
    if(Index > -1) DiagAnalysis = Cartographer[2];
    if(Index > -1) CodeAnalysis = Cartographer[3].indexOf("F33.0");
    if(Index > -1) console.println(CodeAnalysis);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the array?

Comment: Where's the array ?

Comment: ...and the code you're using to access the array...

Answer (score 0):

`Medical1` is already declared as a [string literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) at

```
var Medical1 = "xanax";
```

`String` does not have a built-in `.valueAsString` or `.value` property.

Omitting addressing the remainder of the code, substitute referencing `Medical1` for `Medical1.valueAsString` and `Medical1.value`

```
if (Medical1 != "") {}
```

and

```
Index = fileArray[i].indexOf(Medical1);
```